# Where is the post? Where is the discussion?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, editing

My post says "This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta." But I don't see any information on it anywhere in meta.

What's going on here?

Comment: Reasons were given for the edits made to your post [in the revision history](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/16527/revisions) and reiterated [in comments](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/989/do-christians-and-muslims-worship-the-same-god/16527#comment40456_16527). At this point if you would like to dispute those reasons, the impetus is on you to post here and get some community feedback. If you want to appeal to the community the thing to do is [edit] this post with your actual specific concern.

Comment: As for the bit of your question asking "What's going on here?", that part has been explained already. For the sake of making it easier on those just joining the situation, here is [a link to a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9099/) where instructions about taking any issues you have here to meta. If you have any issues, the place to get them settled is here, but this question currently doesn't have anything for us to solve. Please [edit] this question with specifics of anything you want clarification on or to raise concerns about the handling of your posts.

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that if you have a question about the fact that the post is locked, you should raise a question on meta about why the question is locked.

If you have a question about why the question was locked, I'd recommend asking that.